# What is the best practice of customizing the Bash prompt (aka the PS1 environment variable)?

Tags: bash, git, bashrc, .profile, ps1

I am trying to add Git branch name to my Bash prompt by changing the `PS1` variable like this:

```
PS1=`echo "$PS1" | sed 's/\\\\\$ $/\$(__git_ps1)\\\\\$ /'`
```

And if I understand correctly, it is not recommended to update `~/.bashrc` for personalizing purposes. All articles I found suggest updating either `.profile` or `.bash_profile` for such purposes. So I am looking for a perfect place to put this line into.

These are the places I've tried so far:

- `.profile`: not sourced by `gnome-terminal`
- `.bash_profile`: not sourced by `gnome-terminal`
- `.bash_login`: not sourced by `gnome-terminal`
- `.bash_aliases`: works, but I don't think `PS1` has anything to do with aliases

I am using Ubuntu Desktop and I work in `gnome-terminal` or `byobu`, so I have to find a file which is sourced when I start `bash` in an X environment. Then I looked in `.bashrc` for other files it sources after assigning a value to `PS1`. There are `.bash_aliases` and `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` which I don't think are proper for this purpose.

What are other choices? And what is the best practice of customizing Bash prompt?

Comment: "And if I understand correctly, it is not recommended ..." - can you give is the source you are attempting to understand?

Comment: And you might be better off using Bash's string substitution directly: `PS1="${PS1/\$ /\$(__git_ps1)\$ }"`.

Comment: Thanks @muru for your suggestion. That looks much cooler than what I had!

Comment: And I did a search again but unfortunately I couldn't find the articles which I thought suggested against updating .bashrc. Maybe I interpreted it wrong.

Comment: I did some experiments and this is my final version of the substitution: `PS1="${PS1/%\\$ /\$(__git_ps1)\\$ }"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the following HOWTO, your `.bashrc` is actually the best place to tweak $PS1:

> the PS1 string should be set in `.bashrc`. this is because non-interactive bashes go out of their way to unset PS1. the bash man
>   page tells how the presence or absence of PS1 is a good way of knowing
>   whether one is in an interactive vs non-interactive (ie script) bash
>   session.
>
> [...]
>
> therefore it should be stressed that `PS1=..blah..` should be in `.bashrc` and not `.profile`.

Source: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/setps.html

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @sylvain-pineau that it should be located in .bashrc.

Im using a git-prompt shell script that I've forked on github. It works very well with git, svn and hg. It shows you which branch you are in, which files you have that is new, which files that is changed (in different colors) and the status from your last bash command.

You can download it like this:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stalet/git-prompt/master/git-prompt.sh
chmod +x git-prompt.sh
```

Then in .bashrc i'm using a test to see if my git-prompt script is available and then source it:

```
[[ -s ~/config/git-prompt.sh ]] && source ~/config/git-prompt.sh
```

Disclaimer, i am a commiter to the git-prompt github project.

Comment: Guess this looks too heavy for me since I am only using git and not svn nor hg. Plus, I don't like my console to be too colorful, I get anxious sometimes (-_-). So I think I'll accept @sylvain-pineau 's answer. But still, thanks.